# As if by solitude to convey the meaning almost in the state of solitude

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

This should be a title for an art-work. Is it grammatically correct to write "As if by solitude" to mean a mental state near or similar to [solitude](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solitude), but not completely?

Any helps and hints are appreciated!

Comment: Not really. The construction ***as if by** [magic, accident, instinct, chance,...]* is normally used in contexts where whatever's being described is very specifically *not* attributable to *magic, accident, instinct.* The phenomenon *looks* as if it was caused by the specified "reason", but we normally only use this construction in contexts where we know the "superficially likely" candidate is *not* the cause or mechanism. But I have no idea what ***as if by solitude*** would be supposed to mean anyway, so it's a bit academic.

Comment: A sentence can be grammatically correct without meaning anything.  We say _in solitude_, not _by_.

Comment: @KateBunting Could you please elaborate on what "in solitude" means?

Comment: It means 'alone'!